# How to eager load and include the children of an ICollection only using include?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, eager-loading

The issue I am having involves virtual ICollections of collections not being considered as properties when using include, while still being able to be accessed as such at runtime.

For example `LoanClass`:

```cs
public class Loan : BaseEntity
{
    private ICollection<LoanStatus> _LoanStatuses;

    public virtual ICollection<LoanStatus> LoanStatuses
    {
        get { return _LoanStatuses ?? (_LoanStatuses = new Collection<LoanStatus>()); }
        set { _LoanStatuses = value; }
    }
}

public class LoanStatus : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LoanID { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("LoanID")]
    public virtual Loan Loan { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StatusID")]
    public virtual CodeType Status { get; set; }
}

public class CodeType : BaseEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public int? Sequence { get; set; }

    public bool IsCodeType(CodeTypeCategory category, string code)
    {
        return Category.Equals(category.ToString()) && Code.Equals(code);
    }
}
```

`service layer`:

```cs
Loan loan = LoanUnitOfWork.LoanRepository.LoadByLoanNumberWithRequiredData(loanNumber,l => l.LoanStatuses);
```

`Repository`:

```cs
public Loan LoadByLoanNumberWithRequiredData(string loanNumber, params Expression<Func<Loan, object>>[] includes)
{
    return includes.Aggregate(Context.Loans.AsQueryable()
        ,(current, include) => current.Include(include)).FirstOrDefault(l => l.LoanNumber == loanNumber);
}
```

The issue here is that I can eager load other properties of the loan class because they directly refer to the loan table in the db.

But when I go to eager, load properties on the LoanStatuses table/object like so:

```cs
Loan loan = LoanUnitOfWork.LoanRepository.LoadByLoanNumberWithRequiredData(loanNumber,l => l.LoanStatuses.*Status.Code*);
```

It will not allow me.

And if I leave the italicised code above out of the include query, then the properties are not eager loaded and EF makes many calls out to collect these Status.Codes:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
SELECT [c].[Ct_ID], [c].[Active], [c].[Ct_Category], [c].[Ct_Code], [c].[Ct_CreatedBy], [c].[Ct_DateCreated], [c].[Ct_DateUpdated], [c].[Ct_Description], [c].[Ct_Sequence], [c].[Ct_UpdatedBy]
FROM [Code_Types] AS [c]
WHERE ([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Ct_ID] = @__p_0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (11ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
SELECT [c].[Ct_ID], [c].[Active], [c].[Ct_Category], [c].[Ct_Code], [c].[Ct_CreatedBy], [c].[Ct_DateCreated], [c].[Ct_DateUpdated], [c].[Ct_Description], [c].[Ct_Sequence], [c].[Ct_UpdatedBy]
FROM [Code_Types] AS [c]
WHERE ([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Ct_ID] = @__p_0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (10ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
SELECT [c].[Ct_ID], [c].[Active], [c].[Ct_Category], [c].[Ct_Code], [c].[Ct_CreatedBy], [c].[Ct_DateCreated], [c].[Ct_DateUpdated], [c].[Ct_Description], [c].[Ct_Sequence], [c].[Ct_UpdatedBy]
FROM [Code_Types] AS [c]
WHERE ([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Ct_ID] = @__p_0)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command: Information: Executed DbCommand (312ms) [Parameters=[@__p_0='?' (DbType = Int32)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='600']
SELECT [c].[Ct_ID], [c].[Active], [c].[Ct_Category], [c].[Ct_Code], [c].[Ct_CreatedBy], [c].[Ct_DateCreated], [c].[Ct_DateUpdated], [c].[Ct_Description], [c].[Ct_Sequence], [c].[Ct_UpdatedBy]
FROM [Code_Types] AS [c]
WHERE ([c].[Active] = CAST(1 AS bit)) AND ([c].[Ct_ID] = @__p_0)
```

How can I eager load the child properties of Loan statuses?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/)?

Comment: @JHBonarius many times. It does not include any info about collections of virtual collections.

Comment: For the record, an EF `DbContext` is a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository, so implementing the repository pattern yourself is unnecessary and can cause issues. Create your own services but those services should use the `DbContext` directly. Probably too late to change this project but something to consider for the future. We had our own UOW in my office and used it when we first moved to EF and life was better when we scrapped it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I've never been so against repository patterns in my life

Comment: Repositories aren't that bad and sometimes the only solution. It's _badly implemented_ repositories that give the whole Repository pattern a bad rep. If you're just reproducing a DbSet, then there's no added value. If you "try" to expose `IQueryable` behavior without using `IQueryable`, like done in the repository you show, then IMHO it's just bad design. The ones that designed this repository is making their life, and those of other people that have to use it, very hard.

Comment: For now, the repository should have a specific method `GetByLoanNumberIncludingLoadStatus`, that should eagerly load the required values. If you arent allowed to add anything to the repository, hit the architect over the head for me.

Comment: Well, it is probably possible to handle this: `l => l.LoanStatuses.Select(s => s.Code)`. Not sure that EF Core can handle this but it is possible to transform this expression to translatable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I don't think you can. In [EF6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#eagerly-loading-multiple-levels) you could Include the children of an ICollection using `ICollection.Select()`, which is still valid Syntax in EF Core, but you get an InvalidOperationException:

> InvalidOperationException: The expression 'l.LoanStatuses.AsQueryable().Select(ls=> ls.Status)' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

I had the same Problem, but I found a Solution, that is not exactly what you wanted, but gets the Job done.

Instead of `params Expression<Func<Loan, object>>[] includes` I used `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include` which would look something like that:

```cs
public Loan LoadByLoanNumberWithRequiredData(string loanNumber, Func<IQueryable<Loan>, IIncludableQueryable<Loan, object>> include)
{
    return include(Context.Loans.AsQueryable())
        .FirstOrDefault(l => l.LoanNumber == loanNumber);
}
```

```cs
Loan loan = LoanUnitOfWork.LoanRepository.LoadByLoanNumberWithRequiredData(loanNumber, loan => loan
    .Include(l => l.LoanStatuses).ThenInclude(ls => ls.Status));
```

I know it's not what you asked for, but it's a neat workaround.